# Notified when AppleScript command finishes

Tags: xcode, scripting, applescript

I have the following `AppleScript`:

```
tell application "Finder"
    open file "MyApp.xcworkspace" of folder of (file (path to me))
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    delay 5
    keystroke "u" using {command down}
end tell
```

Basically the script launches XCode and executes the tests. The problem is that the script is marked as finished as soon as the last command is executed. That means the tests start and there is no way to find out whether they are finished or not.

Any ideas about how to determine whether the tests are finished or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you aware that Xcode is scriptable?

```
tell application "System Events" to set myWorkspace to path of file "MyApp.xcworkspace" of container of (path to me)
tell application "Xcode"
    open myWorkspace
    set activeDoc to 1st workspace document
    tell activeDoc
        test
        repeat until completed of last scheme action result
            delay 0.5
        end repeat
        set lastTestResult to last scheme action result
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: I was totally unaware of that. Big thanks for the help :) !